# How to point Wordpress 404 to URL through .htaccess

Tags: linux, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I've created a 404 page within the actual pages itself.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

The code above is used to re-direct 404's, but this is to a file and not a URL?

How can I re-direct 404's to a page within the CMS?

I've tried the following, but to no avail:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.mywebsite.com/my-404-page
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it using the method you suggest you need to include a Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^404/?$ my-404-page.html
```

So together it would then be:

```
RewriteRule ^404/?$ my-404-page.html
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.mywebsite.com/my-404-page/
```

Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/267781/how-to-redirect-only-404-pages-with-htaccess-in-wordpress

As far I understand, .htaccess rewrite rules are executed before the request is proccesed by WordPress, or even by PHP engine, so you can not know if a URL will trigger a 404 error in .htaccess, you can not check if a given path will trigger a 404 at that level. You need to do it in WordPress itself:

```
// See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'cyb_redirect_not_found_paths' );
function cyb_redirect_not_found_paths() {

    // See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_404/
    if( is_404() ) {

        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/your_path' ) {

            $url_to = 'redirecton_rul';

            // See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/
            wp_redirect( $url_to );
            exit;

        }

    }

}
```